# call of overloaded with ref-qualifiers member function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, ref-qualifier, function-qualifier

I found a strange behaviour, when compliling my code with **G++** (**gcc** 4.8.1 and **MinGW** 4.8.2 with `-std=gnu++1y` flag). In spirit of SSCCE I isolating the following snippet:

```
struct C
{

    template< typename X >
    auto
    f(X &&) const &
    { ; }

    template< typename X >
    auto
    f(X &&) &
    { ; }

    template< typename X >
    auto
    f(X &&) &&
    { ; }

};

int main()
{
    int i{};
#if 1
    C{}.f(i);
#endif
#if 1
    C c{};
    c.f(i);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

It gives an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:10: error: call of overloaded 'f(int&)' is ambiguous
     c.f(i);
          ^
main.cpp:29:10: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:6:5: note: auto C::f(X&&) const & [with X = int&]
     f(X &&) const &
     ^
main.cpp:11:5: note: auto C::f(X&&) & [with X = int&]
     f(X &&) &
     ^
main.cpp:16:5: note: auto C::f(X&&) && [with X = int&]
     f(X &&) &&
     ^
```

But in case of `#if 1` and `#if 0`, or `#if 0` and `#if 1` it compiles normally. Also if I replace all `auto`'s with `void`'s, then all compiles successfully too.

Is it bug, or just my misleading?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like the perfect forwarding mechanism (the deducation rules for rvalue references for C++11) is screwing you up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward. Basically, in `template <typename T> void foo(T&& t)`, the `T&&` actually acts as a "universal" reference rather than a rhr. The actual deduction rules are...super confusing to me though.

Comment: Another link: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: @MadScienceDreams it not matters much, because if we substitute all occurences of `X &&` to `X const &`, then everything remains the same.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in the interaction between ref-qualifiers and return type deduction in g++. [clang at Coliru (post 3.4 trunk version) compiles the program without complaint](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8152dcf3e8f7455). [g++ at Coliru (4.8.2) refuses to compile it even with the members non-templated](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682de1f3fe6567d7). It would be nice if someone could run it past 4.9.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams this code is pretty simple as compared with its prototype *bitbucket.org/insituc/variant*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ 4.8.2 has the same problem with the even simpler ([Live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f49fe209d6e40dc5)):

```
struct A {
    auto f() & {}
    auto f() && {}
};

int main() {
    A{}.f();
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

despite the program obviously being correct. It appears to be a bug in the interaction between ref-qualifiers and return type deduction: presumably the deduction process is stripping the qualifiers from the implicit object argument before handing them off to overload resolution.

I have reported this as [GCC bug 60943](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60943).